# Could not find property 'IndexAllFields' on object of type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration

Tags: content-search

[image]

I have tried adding **IndexAllFields** as **true** in *C:\inetpub\wwwroot\subway93sc.dev.local\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config*.
But it does not work.

Could you please provide me with any suggestion to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexAllFields` is a property of `SolrDocumentBuilderOptions`, not `SolrIndexConfiguration`.

Try using patch like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
          <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>
          </documentOptions>
        </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This has already been added for SolrDocumentBuilderOptions but not sure why this error is happening...

Comment: The above patch options  <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>  is already available for SolrDocumentBuilderOptions but not sure why this error is happening for SolrIndexConfiguration

Comment: It's because `SolrIndexConfiguration` class doesn't have that property. You cannot add properties to .net types from code. It's `SolrDocumentBuilderOptions` which takes care of `indexAllFields`. Why do you even try to set it on  `SolrIndexConfiguration`?